# How to access specific keys/values in a dictionary C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am building a flash card application to help me study in High School. The user enters terms and definitions in a dictionary. Now I can't figure out how to set the labels to randomly show a term and its definition. My methods code goes something like this:

```
public void startQuiz()
{
   Random random = new Random();
   int randNum;

   //My dictionary with all the terms and 
   //definitions is called terms

   randomNum = random.Next(terms.Count);
   termLabel.Text = // ???
   definitionLabel.text = //???
}
```

I hope that is coherent enough. I basically want the randomNum to index a specific key and value from my dictionary of "terms." Then set the termLabel text to the chosen key value (which is a string), and the definitionLabel text to the specified value (also a string). I will be happy to provide clarification, as I am barely learning how to use visual c#

Here is my dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, string> terms = new Dictionary<string, string>()

//Here is how terms get added
private void addTermButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    term = termBox.Text;
    definition = definitionBox.Text;
    terms.Add(term, definition);
    //Clear text boxes for more terms and definitions
    termBox.Text = "";
    definitionBox.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: in fact picking some random item is easy but the difficult thing is to get the best **performance**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to use an `OrderedDictionary`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx

You will be then able to use an index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq to retrieve a Tuple. Be aware that this is not necessarily the order by which the elements were inserted into the dictionary.

```
 var tuple = terms.ElementAt(randNum);
 TitleLabel = tuple.Key;
 DescriptionLabel = tuple.Value;
```